# LAMP server, how to do I tell if I should get separate Apache and MySQL?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, centos

I have a standard LAMP server hosted on a VPS. The server currently has 2 GBs of RAM and over the last month I have been having lots of server crashes (the server runs out of RAM). Sometimes, daily. After dropping my MaxClients down to something my web server can handle, the crashes have dropped a little bit, but I would like to handle the traffic a little better. I think it is time for me to upgrade hardware again, but I am not sure if I should just throw more ram at this VPS or if I should get multiple servers and have a dedicated DB server and another dedicated Apache server.

I know you guys will probably need more information than this, so please just let me know if you need anything else.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a LAMP stack, or did you install (and configure) the components separately?

Comment: What sort of analysis have you already done for it?

Comment: I installed and configured the components separately. Although I use the word configure, very lightly. I just made it work :P I have used MySQL tuner script, to chose some settings, and apachebuddy to help with the Apache setup. I've also looked at top to try and see where everything is at when the server is running well. I am really a programmer and not so much of a hardware person, so I haven't done much else to analyze the site, because I am not totally sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Throw more RAM at it.  In the world of servers yours is tiny, and separating out your services on to 2+ servers could be a lot of work that isn't required and introduces more potential points of failure that you'll have to risk assess and code for.  Just upgrade your package - one phone call, no code, problem solved.